# regex operator OR - preg_match_all

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have string `{tender id="2,3"}` or `{tender catid="2" id="2,3"}` or `{tender catid="2"}`

I use

```
$regex = "/{tender ((.*?id\s*=\s*['\"](.*?)['\"]) (.*?id\s*=\s*['\"](.*?)['\"]))}/";
```

but work only if i have in string both id and catid....How can i write regex to work if only one parameter is in string?

Comment: seperate the two by a logical or operator |

Comment: if i put $regex = "/{tender ((.*?catid\s*=\s*['\"](.*?)['\"]) | (.*?id\s*=\s*['\"](.*?)['\"]))}/"; i get all id in string...not just in {tender ....}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `{tender (?:cat)?id="(\d+,?)+"}`

You may need to specify additional details if it doesn't work for you. As you requested, it will only match when either `catid` or just `id` is in the data structure (case 1 and 3 for your examples).

## Explanation

- `{tender` the start of the data.
- `(?:cat)?` catch `cat` if it can
- `id="` gets the start of an id
- `(\d+,?)+` gets digits that may or may not be followed by a comma
- `"}` End of the data.